# Selenium Firefox driver fails on Ubuntu 23

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04, and my Python code fails (used to work on version 22).

If I run this snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
driver.quit()
```

I get:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable

Firefox version is 119, geckodriver version is 0.33.0.

When I give it an explicit path to Firefox:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.binary = FirefoxBinary('/snap/bin/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
driver.quit()
```

the result is the same.

If I start Firefox from the command line as

> /snap/bin/firefox

it starts fine, but gives a couple of warnings:

> Gtk-Message: 07:42:43.330: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
> Gtk-Message: 07:42:43.433: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by removing firefox snap and installing it via apt as described in
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

This worked perfectly for Ubuntu 23.